# How to pass value from dataprovider to create/edit page

Tags: react-admin

I am creating a react-admin application in which after uploading image to server, response will contain image_id which I have to update in create/edit page of that module.

I tried updating record but it is not getting updated.

```
class ImageUpload extends Component {
    handleClick = (params) => {
        const { push, record, showNotification } = this.props;
        const updatedRecord = { ...record, is_approved: true };
        var imgElement = document.getElementById('series_image');
        console.log(record)
        if(imgElement.files && imgElement.files[0]){
            var filereader = new FileReader();
            filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(imgElement.files[0]);
            filereader.onload = function(e) {
                fetch(`http://localhost:53111/b/admin/img/v1/upload`, { 
                    method: 'POST', 
                    body : filereader.result,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => record.image_id = data.imageId)
                .catch((e) => {
                    showNotification('Error: comment not approved', 'warning')
                });
            }


        }
    }

    render() {
        return <input type='file' id="series_image" onChange={this.handleClick} />;
    }   
}
```

image_id is getting updated in dataprovider

id: 2798
*image_id: "269"*
isTour: 1
is_confirmed: 1
is_history_present: 0
is_video_present: 1

But while updating the record image_id is restored to default value

id: 2798
*image_id: 0*
isTour: 1
is_confirmed: 1
is_history_present: 0
is_video_present: 1

Please guide me on how to update record after we get response from server.

Answer (score 0):

When displaying data, react-admin gets data from Redux state:  `admin.resource."my_resource_name".data`

With your download method, you don't modify Redux state properly.

File download example:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload

Querying the API:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html

Comment: I tried updating using setState but getting **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: this.setState is not a function). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.** Not sure how to modify Redux state `.then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({imageId:parseInt(data.imageId)})
                })`

Comment: To change the state of Redux, you must create and dispatch the Redux action.